# The host Kernel kills mysql:5.6 container (Arch Linux)

Tags: ddev

When trying to start a project with MySQL 5.6, the ddev health check for the db container fails.

```bash
mkdir ddev-test-mysql56 && cd $_
ddev config --database mysql:5.6
ddev start
```

```
$ ddev start
Starting ddev-test-mysql56... 
 Network ddev-ddev-test-mysql56_default  Created 
 Container ddev-ddev-test-mysql56-web  Created 
 Container ddev-ddev-test-mysql56-db  Created 
 Container ddev-ddev-test-mysql56-db  Started 
 Container ddev-ddev-test-mysql56-web  Started 
Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: db container failed: log=, err=container exited, please use 'ddev logs -s db' to find out why it failed 
 Container ddev-router  Created 
 Container ddev-router  Started 
Failed to start ddev-test-mysql56: container(s) failed to become healthy before their configured timeout or in 120 seconds. This may be just a problem with the healthcheck and not a functional problem. (container 'db' exited, please use 'ddev logs -s db' to find out why it failed)
```

It returns very quickly so that gave me the idea that the healthcheck has not really run yet.

`ddev logs -s db` has no errors and ends with:

```
+ echo 'MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.'

+ echo
MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.

+ echo 'Starting mysqld.'
Starting mysqld.
+ exec mysqld --server-id=0
+ tail -f /var/log/mysqld.log
```

I tried running the DDEV DB container alone:

```
docker run --rm --user mysql drud/ddev-dbserver-mysql-5.6:v1.21.5
# (exits with status 137)
```

I checked the syslog of the host. Since my system is running `systemd`, I executed `journalctl -f` (for others it would be `tail -f /var/log/syslog`) while producing the error.

I found there that the Kernel Out-Of-Memory killer killed `mysqld` after it took 10GB RAM (with an empty database) after a second or so.

The problem is with the base MySQL 5.6 as well:

```
docker run --rm mysql:5.6
```

(5.6 is EOL, but maybe someone has an idea or just the problem description helps someone when running into the problem)

(Host: Manjaro Linux, Kernel 6.3)

Comment: The DDEV automated tests run this on amd64 and arm64 (but Ubuntu and macOS) and it seems to be fine. https://github.com/ddev/ddev/blob/2d481a419f1745b6807da9eaf3781df53e75a4e1/pkg/ddevapp/ddevapp_test.go#L1594-L1798

Comment: @easleyfixed RAM (I'll make that clearer)

Comment: If you are facing a bug with existing software, without having changed anything on your own, please use their bug tracker to get support - especially if you could also track this down to other parts of software, like the MySQL container in your case

Comment: I guess this is an Arch/Manjaro Linux problem, as it runs fine on Ubuntu, `docker run -it -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root --rm mysql:5.6`